# Storing multiple user inputs into multiple separate arrays

Tags: java, arrays, input

I am EXTREMELY new to programming. I am trying to write a program that allows users to enter in their college / university transcripts course by course. I would like each course to be separated in their own array and separated by spaces.

For example: ENG 105 A 3 (array 1) MAT 102 A 4 (array 2) etc...

It seems as if the input is being stored into one single array.

It would be awesome if I did not have to use a counter and the program could move on when users are done entering their courses.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tester{

public static void main(String[] args) {

 int length;
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.println("How many courses did you complete at your college / university?: ");
 length = input.nextInt();  

 String[] courses = new String[length];

 System.out.println("Follow this model when entering your courses: ENG 105 3 A");

 for(int counter = 0; counter < length; counter++){
  System.out.println("Course "+(counter+1));
  courses[counter] = input.next();   
 }

 input.close();

}

}
```

Comment: It seems like there are two issues here. 1. you would like three arrays. 2. you would like a better way to end user input. I'm not sure what the benefit of #1 is. Do you want `String[] courses` to be `String[][] courses`? To end user input you could have the user enter `done` and check for that string to exit the loop.

Comment: I was thinking I could create a student object and then have an arraylist inside of that object that holds the courses... And maybe when I implement a GUI I could have a “complete” button?

Comment: Other suggestion would be to use a list of object: List<Course> ... where Course is a class with 4 attributes (e.g.. ENG. 105, A and 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 2 points to fix: Handle data (ENG-105-3-A) and buffer.

```
String[][] courses = new String[length][4];

System.out.println("Follow this model when entering your courses: ENG-105-3-A");

for(int counter = 0; counter < length; counter++){
    System.out.println("Course "+(counter+1));

    //Solution
    courses[counter] = input.next().split("-");  //data are separated by "-"

    input.nextLine(); //Cleanning buffer

}
```

Comment: This is working. I am trying to figure out how to print single courses. For example, the third course you entered is (print 3rd entered course here).

Comment: @AddiFamer, try this to print courses:
 
        System.out.println("\nEntered Stuffs.!");
        int nbr=0;
        for(String[] cours:courses){
            System.out.println("Course "+nbr++);
            for(String s:cours)
                System.out.print(s+" ");
            System.out.println();
        }
(so lat but try it, if you are not jet got it)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want something like this would work:

```
String[][] courses = new String[length][];

System.out.println("Follow this model when entering your courses: ENG 105 3 A");

for (int counter = 0; counter < length; counter++){
    System.out.println("Course "+(counter+1));
    courses[counter] = input.nextLine().split("\\s+");   
}
```

Since this is splitting the course, it generates an array of arrays, that looks like this:

```
[["ENG","105","A","3"], ["MAT", "102", "A", "4"]]
```

On the other hand, if you want to stop the input when the user enters a keyword, you need something like this:

```
List<String[]> courses = new ArrayList<String[]>;

System.out.println("Follow this model when entering your courses: ENG 105 3 A");
String course = input.next();
while (!course.equals("end")){
    courses.add(course.split("\\s+"));  
    String course = input.nextLine(); 
}
```

Comment: After input.next(), buffer should be cleanned

Comment: To get this to work i needed to add the array size of 4 in the bracket next to length. I also had to add input.HasNextLine. Thank you! :)